# reducing a column of CSV lists to a single list

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

I'm using Python3 to read a column from an Excel spreadsheet:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
df = pd.read_excel('MWE.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(df)

                   col1                        col2
0         starts normal                  egg, bacon
1  still none the wiser         egg, sausage, bacon
2      maybe odd tastes                   egg, spam
3     or maybe post-war            egg, bacon, spam
4  maybe for the hungry   egg, bacon, sausage, spam
5                 bingo  spam, bacon, sausage, spam
```

I want to reduce `col2` to a single list of the words in col2 (e.g. egg, bacon,...).

`df.col2.ravel()` seems to reduce `col2` to a list of strings.

`df.col2.flatten()` yields

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

1. Turn series of comma separated strings into a list of lists

   ```
   arrs = df.col2.map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(',')]).tolist()
   # [['egg', 'bacon'], ['egg', 'sausage', 'bacon'], ...]
   ```
2. Get list with unique items

   ```
   unique = list({elem for arr in arrs for elem in arr})
   # ['spam', 'sausage', 'egg', 'bacon']
   ```

Comment: Beautiful - thank you: that's exactly right, and went a step further to predict what I wanted to do next.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to have a Series of list as the col2, this will do the trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['starts normal','still none the wiser'], 'col2': ['egg, bacon','egg, sausage, bacon']})

df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(',')])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                   col1                   col2
0         starts normal           [egg, bacon]
1  still none the wiser  [egg, sausage, bacon]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've edited my description to be clarify that I'm looking for a single list of words as my output, e.g. [egg, bacon, egg, sausage, bacon...].  How do I flatten the output produced from your code into a single list of words?

Answer (score 1):

Try something simple like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [list('abc'), list('de'), list('fghi')]})
flat_col2 = [element for row in df.col2 for element in row]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Comment: Thank you.  This gives me a list of individual characters: I've edited my description to clarify that I'd like a list of words.  Do you know if there's a simple way of altering the iteration to do so over words rather than characters?